# How do I change the bulb

Tags: bulb

Can some one tell me how to change a bulb in this light please?[image]

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Can you post a picture or two from the side? There may be some set screws holding the bowl on, that would be just below the ceiling. In fact, it looks like there may be one at the bottom of the picture, just to the left of the while orb...

Comment: What country are you in? First, get a working torch. Switch off the electricity supply to that fixture at the fusebox - there are likely to be "circuit breakers" for several electrical circuits. They *should* be labelled as to what they do. Switch on the light so that the remaining bulbs are illuminated, then switch off the appropriate circuit breaker. Confirm that the light has gone off before proceeding.

Comment: there not just a [G40 or G30](https://5fc98fa113f6897cea53-06dfa63be377ed632ae798753ae0fb3f.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/product_images/files/000/012/440/legacy_product_detail_large/634_09e9a05a88b9e2e54b692100b0df82016a6e2483_original.jpg?1429820063) that unscrews are they?

Comment: Cue the "how many SE readers does it take to change a light bulb" responses :-)

Answer (score 1):

THere are either 3 screws holding the glass over the bulb or the glass itself is "threaded" into the fixture.  Would need a picture of where the glass enters the light fixture to be sure.